# How do you use the [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:] method?

Tags: objective-c

How do you use the [`[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method?

I would appreciate it if someone could post some example code. (There is no example in the documentation.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
NSDate * OneHourAway = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600]
```

The argument is in seconds.  3600 = 60 * 60 = 60 minutes = 1 hour

Comment: can we use 30*24*60*60 for a month or else 2592000 in the interval

Comment: How to use it in swift.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NSDate property called datePicker 
then see a possible use of dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
}
```

This will cause the datepicker to allow only dates that are 60 seconds from now